# What is the difference between CountableRange's startIndex and lowerBound?

Tags: swift, collections, range

[Documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/countablerange):

> The associated Bound type is both the element and index type of CountableRange. Each element of the range is its own corresponding index. The lower bound of a CountableRange instance is its start index, and the upper bound is its end index.

`var lowerBound: Bound { get }` is declared

```
var lowerBound: Bound
The range's lower bound.

In an empty range, lowerBound is equal to upperBound.

Declaration
var lowerBound: Bound { get }
```

`var startIndex: Bound { get }` is declared

```
var startIndex: Bound
The position of the first element in a nonempty collection.

If the collection is empty, startIndex is equal to endIndex.

Declaration
var startIndex: Bound { get }
```

Is there any difference between these two, and how do I decide which one to use?

Comment: No difference as it says **The lower bound of a CountableRange instance is its start index**

Comment: Use the source: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Range.swift.gyb#L139: `public var startIndex: Index { return lowerBound  }`

Comment: Note that given the standard library makes the direct use of `CountableRange`'s `subscript` deliberately ambiguous, you shouldn't need to use the `startIndex` and `endIndex` properties *directly*. They're only really meant for when the range is treated as a generic collection.

Answer (score 5):

`lowerBound` and `startIndex` are fully equivalent for a `CountableRange`, as are `upperBound` and `endIndex`, as stated by the documentation:

> The lower bound of a CountableRange instance is its start index, and the upper bound is its end index.

The only reason why`CountableRange` provides both properties is that [`startIndex` and `endIndex` are required by the `Collection` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection) while [`lowerBound` and `upperBound` are common to all Range types](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/range#lowerbound) (i.e.: CountableRange, CountableClosedRange, etc.).